# Angular 8 , angular chosen not working after build

Tags: django, angular, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

Currently I am developing website using Django and angular 8. for drop-down I have used angular-chosen and I have configured it in angular side using angular-chosen package.

On Angular side dropdown working properly with angular-chosen and I am able to get expected results as shown in SS below.

[image]

But after build into my django application, angular chosen not able to load.I have attached screenshot as below.
[image]

I have done same configuration as have been suggested in below plunker.
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/N5KF1d

I have found another strange behavior that It working most of times with firefox browser and but not working with chrome browser.

I have tried a lot to find solution but not able to. So guys please let me know if anyone have solution for it.

Thanks.

Comment: So you are populating the list using data from Django backend? Have you checked that data is not getting blocked?

Comment: yes i have checked data is not blocked because some times data show and some time it does not.